# Lebesgue measurable implies caratheodory measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The definition of Lebesgue measure is

> $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if $\forall \epsilon > 0,$ there exists an open set $O$ such that $E \subset O$ and $m_*(O-E) < \epsilon$.

Caratheorody measurable is

> $E$ is Caratheodory measurable, if $m_*(A) = m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c)$ for all $A \in \Omega$.

I want to show that the top definition implies the bottom definition. Since $m_*(A) \le m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c)$ is trivial by subadditivity, we only need to show $m_*(A) \ge m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c)$. In order to use the Lebesgue measurability, let $E$ be Lebesgue measurable, and let $O$ be some open set such that $A \subset O$. Then
\begin{align*}
 m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c) \le m_*(O \cap E) + m_*(O \cap E^c)
\end{align*}
But I'm not sure where I go from there. I want to use $\epsilon$ somewhere but I'm not sure how. Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using $m_*$ to mean the **outer** measure? Usually the outer mesure is represented as $m^*$.

Comment: @Ramiro Yes, I'm using $m_*$ to denote exterior measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. This is the notation used in my textbok.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: See https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/spring11/section1.5.pdf for a simpler solution (note that the Lebesgue outer measure of $E$ is denoted by $|E|_e$ in the document).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Attention**: We are going to use the terminology used in the question, including $m_*$ to denote Lebesgue outer measure:

> $E$ is Lebesgue measurable if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $O$ such that $E \subset O$ and $m_*(O-E) < \epsilon$.
>
> and
>
> $E$ is Caratheodory measurable, if $m_*(A) = m_*(A \cap E) + m_*(A \cap E^c)$ for all $A \subseteq \Omega$.

Let us prove that if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $E$ is Caratheodory measurable.

Suppose $E$ is is Lebesgue measurable. Given any $\epsilon >0$, let $O_\epsilon$ be an open set such that  $E \subset O_\epsilon$ and $m_*(O_\epsilon-E) < \epsilon$.

Given any $A \subseteq \Omega$, we have, taking any  any $\epsilon >0$
\begin{align*}
\mu_*(A) &\leqslant \mu_*(A \cap E) + \mu(A\cap E^c) \\
& \leqslant \mu_*(A \cap O_\epsilon ) + \mu_*((A\cap O_\epsilon ^c) \cup (A\cap O_\epsilon \cap E^c))\\
&  \leqslant \mu_*(A \cap O_\epsilon ) + \mu_*(A\cap O_\epsilon ^c) +\mu_*(A\cap O_\epsilon \cap E^c)\\
& \leqslant \mu_*(A \cap O_\epsilon ) + \mu_*(A\cap O_\epsilon ^c) +\mu_*(O_\epsilon \cap E^c)\\
&  \leqslant \mu_*(A) + \epsilon
\end{align*}
where in the last step we used the fact that open sets are Caratheodory measurable.

So we have proved that, for any  $\epsilon >0$,
$$
\mu_*(A) \leqslant \mu_*(A \cap E) + \mu(A\cap E^c) \leqslant \mu_*(A) + \epsilon
$$
So
$$
\mu_*(A) = \mu_*(A \cap E) + \mu(A\cap E^c) 
$$
So $E$ is Caratheodory measurable.

Comment: I think you meant $E$ is Caratheodory measurable at the end. Otherwise, thank you so much for the detailed answer. It all makes sense now!

Comment: @MoneyBall , Yes, you are right. In the last line I meant: "So $E$ is Caratheodory measurable.". I have fixed it, thanks.  You are welcome. I am happy I could help you.